# How can I change my component to use RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to get familiar with RxJs and for the learning purpose I want to know how to change following code or is it even possible.

In my project I have component `MeetingObjectComponent` that also has child `ChatComponent`. Both of them have some animations to expand them that are triggered whenever user clicks on `MeetingObjectComponent`. The problem is that I need to prevent user from spam-clicking the components bcs it makes animation trigger multiple times that is forbidden. Currently in the `ChatComponent` template I keep track of @trigger.done event and emit on it signalizing the parent component that this element is clickable again.

Here are the components themself.

```
Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css'],
  animations:[trigger('openClose', [...])]  
})
export class ChatComponent {
  @Input() isExpanded: boolean | undefined;

  @Output() animationComplete = new EventEmitter<null>();
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-meeting-object',
  templateUrl: './meeting-object.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./meeting-object.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('highlightDim', [...])
  ]
})
export class MeetingObjectComponent {
  @Input() public meetingData: Meeting | undefined;

  public isExpanded: boolean = false;
  public isChildAnimationComplete: boolean = true;

///This method is bound to (click)
  expand(): void { 
    if (this.isChildAnimationComplete) {
      this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
      this.isChildAnimationComplete = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the snippet of `MeetingObjectComponent` template

```
<div class="meeting" (click)="expand()" [@highlightDim]="isExpanded">
  </div>
<app-chat
  [isExpanded]="isExpanded"
  (animationComplete)="isChildAnimationComplete = true"
></app-chat>
```

I want to know how can I implement the same mechanism using RxJs if it is possible

Comment: Not sure of the broader context of what you're trying to accomplish, but have you considered leveraging built-in animation events like `(@highlightDim.done)="isChildAnimationComplete = true"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `(click)="expand()"`, what about using [`RxJs.fromEvent`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) like below

In your component HTML file

```
<div #meeting class="meeting" [@highlightDim]="isExpanded"></div>
```

And in your component TypeScript file

```
destroy$ = new Subject()

@ViewChild('meeting')
divRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  fromEvent(this.divRef.nativeElement, 'click')
    .pipe(
      throttleTime(300),
      tap(() => expand())  // or emit the output 
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),  // don't forget to unsubscribe
    )
    .subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next()
  this.destroy$.complete()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on unsubscribing? Because from Angular docs I've seen that it can have additional logic using the ```return``` keyword but I wasn't able to find additional info on this topic. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Your answer was almost it, thanks! Only difference from actual solution is that I had to use throttleTime() instead of debounceTime(). The reason is that I need to block animation after it starts rather than starting after last user input